# AngularJS - How to add child objects during edit and then PUT

Tags: angularjs, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I'm getting started with AngularJS with Web API and EF on the back end. I have an edit form that is populated via a GET request which returns a Boat object.  One of Boat's properties is an Images array.

If the user adds images to Boat then I need records to be inserted into the database for each new image when the boat is updated. (But obviously not for images that the boat already had prior to edit.)

The current Web API function is:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put(int id, Boat boat)
```

It seems I could either:

a) Push any newly added images to $scope.Boat.Images prior to the PUT. Then in the Web API function, loop through the received Boat.Images, check if a database record exists for that image, if no record exists add the image record to the database.  This seems a bit uneconomical because I'm looping through every existing image and checking if it actually exists in the db already.

or

b) Send a separate object "newImages" with the PUT.  Then I guess the Web API function would be:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put(int id, Boat boat, string[] newImages)
```

This would have the benefit of not having to check which images already exist vs new ones. ie. Everything in newImages gets added to the database.  But, is it weird from an AngularJS point of view to separate the new images from the Boat.Images collection?

Would you do a) or b) or... c) some other way?

Answer (score 0):

I'll do `A` as it fits more the Restful approach.

Now `Images` could be an Array of complex object instead of Array of `string`, therefore you would have a property `ID`.

Then on the WebAPI side, you just add the `Images` without IDs set.

```
var newImages = Boat.Images.Select(x => x.Id == null);
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "it fits more the Restful approach"?  
  
Good point about checking for images without Id's - it just needs to be:    
`var newImages = Boat.Images.Where(x => x.Id == 0);`